# How to remove padding between grid of ImageButtons

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

I have the next XML with 4 Imagebuttons , I've set the images in two LinearLayouts and i gave the buttons weight of 1 so they will be oredered in the same line ,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bt5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="btClick"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="empty" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:onClick="btClick"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/bt6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tag="empty"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:onClick="btClick"
            android:id="@+id/bt7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="empty"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:onClick="btClick"
            android:id="@+id/bt8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:tag="empty"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And as you can there are empty space between the buttons , is there a way to remove that space and make the stick to each other?
[image]

Comment: I had a same issue, I just fixed it by adding `margins with negative value`

Comment: set android:backgroung="@null" 
or set transparent color or set any other color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use remove that by adding either:

`android:background="@null`"

or:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

or:

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```

to the `ImageButton`.

But you will not be able to identify the buttons. You should add different background colors or borders to separate them

Comment: Thanks the background null did it best :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- ( using `android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"` or `android:layout_marginRight="-3dp"`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="btClick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:tag="empty"
        android:layout_marginRight="-3dp" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:onClick="btClick"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/bt6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:tag="empty"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"
        />
```